# Array inside Hash - Some questions

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have this code:

```
a = {}
a["First"] = [true, false]
```

1. How can I read "false"? Tried: `["First"][2]` but output is blank;
2. How can I check if ["Second"] exist or if its array length > 0? Tried `if a["Second"] is nil end` or `if a["Second"].value.length>0` but both seems incorrect;
3. How can I push/pop a new "true" value inside the existing `a["First"]`'s array?
4. How can I delete from `a` the `["First"]` index? (such as `a.pop["First"]`)

Can you help me?

Comment: if you want to read false, you should do a["First"][1] not a["First"][2]

Comment: Right! My fault... -3 to go! Thanks

Comment: a["First"] = a["First"].push('else') to push value

Comment: Seems to works! But also without `a["First"] = `

Comment: also works without `a["First"] =` and for `pop` use it instead of `push` and there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby arrays are 0 based so the elements are 0 and 1; there is not 2. Use: `a["First"][1]`

`a["Second"].nil?` is true if there is no "Second" element of the hash. Use `size` to get array length, so: `a["Second"].size` once you know "Second" exists.

Use: `a["First"].push true`

Use: a["First"].pop

(`a["First"]` gets you to the array; `a` alone is the hash made up of the two arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

combining all comments:

if you want to read false, you should do `a["First"][1]` not `a["First"][2]`

`a["First"].push('else')` to push value

```
a.delete("First")
```